# How to add id attribute to Zend Framework form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have simple class which extends Zend_Form with 2 elements:

```
class Application_Form_Player extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('text', 'firstName', array(
                'label' => $this->getView()->translate('First name') . ' (' . $this->getView()->translate('imaginary') . ')',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                'validators' => array(array('StringLength', false, array(1, 256)))
            )
        );
        $this->addElement('text', 'lastName', array(
                'label' => $this->getView()->translate('Last name') . ' (' . $this->getView()->translate('imaginary') . ')',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                'validators' => array(array('StringLength', false, array(1, 256)))
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Is there a Zend_Form method that I can use to add "id" attribute to the HTML "dl" created by this class?

This is resulting HTML dl to which I want to add id attribute:

```
<dl class="zend_form">
...
</dl>
```

Comment: `$form->setAttrib('id', 'someId');` this would help you at your controller or view, wherever you see it feasible as per your app

Comment: In my case it would be $this->setAttrib('id', 'someId'); You can post your answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->setAttrib('id', 'someId');`, this would help you where `$this` being the object of your current class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('something');

$element->setAttrib('id','myId')
->setLabel('myLabel')
->setRequired(true);

$this->addElements(array(
     $element
));
```

You can add `validators` and `filters` with `addValidator()` and `addFilter()` too.

Comment: You are talking about form element but I was talking about form itself.