# How to set id attribute to Zend form

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have to set id for Zend Framework form. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612217/how-to-add-id-attribute-to-zend-framework-form)
but it appends some encrypted string at the end of the id.
Following is my code:

```
public function init()
{   
   $this->setAttrib('id', 'my_form');
   $this->setName('form_test');
   $this->setSubmitLabel($this->translate('Save Changes'));
   $this->setValidatePartial(true); 
}
```

In Browser it shows as

```
<input name="instance_name" id="my_form_instance_name-kchovmizxlas" value="" aria-describedby="desc_my_form_instance_name-kchovmizxlas" type="text">
```

Can I use the id name **my_form** in my jQuery code or need to change the attribute.

Comment: Your code sets the id of a form but then you've put the HTML output of a form input element in your question. Which are you trying to set the id for?

Comment: If I set id for html tag as export_csv , `<input value="export" id="export_csv" title="Exports" style="margin-left: 1%; margin-bottom: 1%" type="button">` then the id of the button will be export_csv. But while creating a zend form the ID will be id="my_form_instance_name-kchovmizxlas". If i use ID of the button in JavaScript, my question is which ID i have to use the encrypted one?